# Spark custom preprocessing estimator

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I want to write a custom `Estimator` for spark's `Pipelines`. It should perform data cleaning tasks. This means some rows will be dropped, some columns dropped, some columns added, some values replaced in existing columns. IT should also store the mean or min for some numeric columns as a NaN replacement.

However,

```
override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = {
   schema.add(StructField("foo", IntegerType))
}
```

only supports adding fields?
I am curious how am I supposed to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that only adding fields is supported by the `StructField` api. However, that does not mean you cannot remove fields, too!

`StructType` has a value member `fields`, which gives you an `Array[StructField]`. You can `.filter()` this array however you see fit (by `name`, `dataType`, or something more complicated), keeping only the columns you want.

Once you've done your filtering, you have two options:

1. add a `StructField` for each new column to the filtered `fields` array and construct a `StructType` from this
2. construct a `StructType` from the `fields` array and add new columns using `.add(...)`.

Comment: Do you know if there will be a performance impact when a column is replaced vs. a new one appended?

Comment: I don't know what the performance costs would be for sure, but in general it will be a function of how expensive your computation is for the new field(s). As long as your work is distributed, as per the nature of spark, you should be okay.

Keep in mind, dataframe operations are performed lazily and when using the dataframe api, the catalyst optimizer will do it's best to optimize your operations. Don't be afraid of ending up with lots and lots of columns in your dataframe.